# Run selenium on a remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, automation, capybara

I am writing integration test for one of my project, using the following gems for the same, rspec, capybara and selenium.

I face the following challenges in the same,

1. I want to run the test on an existing database, i don't want to clear the existing data before or after executing the test.
2. We have a remote server for integration testing. Is it possible to run the test on a remove server? The way i would like to go is after updating the build on integration server, i would like to go for a integration test using selenium.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, we need to do as follows,

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
...
visit('/')
```

Reference: [capybara gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

Answer (score 1):

1. Sorry, but selenium tests cannot be run in a transaction. You have to (for example) dump database and load previously prepared database after executing each test.
2. Yes, it is possible. What solution you're using for continuous integration and build management? What's the problem you're encountering? Can you describe it?

Comment: Thanks for the help socjopata.
What I was looking for is I wanted to run the selenium test on a remote server(our staging server). As the server is running on production database, i don't wanted it to be cleared on or before the test.